# Formatting the DateTime axis on my plot (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to change my date time format to dd-mm or mm-dd but I'm not sure how to do it. I've looked at other stack overflow questions and answers but I think I may have done my plot a little differently to them as I am computing the sum for each of the different days.

```
data = {'date': ['2020-09-01', '2020-09-02', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-04', '2020-09-01'],
    'newcases': [1, 2, 4, 7, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date','newcases'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #converted to datetime

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))
df.groupby('date').newcases.sum().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

This is what I have tried but I am not able to format the x-ticks into the right format (dd-mm). It still looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Can you provide a [mre]? (as text/code ideally, not screenshot)

Comment: I've just changed the original question to a sample data frame. Any help you can offer will be much appreciated! I'm trying to learn Python and have taken a sample COVID-19 dataset to practice on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas creates a new figure/axes when plotting (unless you pass an axes object to it). So you need to **first** plot and **then** change the axis formatter of the plot you just now created (`gca` = get current axes), i.e. just change the order of your last two lines of code:

```
df.groupby('date').newcases.sum().plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've tried this previously but I get an error. The error is 'DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()'

Comment: What Pandas version are you using? Your example works perfectly with the changed order for pandas 1.1.3 and matplotlib 3.3.0, see attached picture in the answer.

Comment: for older versions of pandas you could use `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m')).newcases.sum().plot(kind = 'bar')`

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I've just updated my Anaconda Navigator and it works now. I didn't realise it may have been that I was using a much older version of Anaconda!